# NAN in OpenGL textures

Tags: opengl, glsl, nan

I use 1D, 2D and 3D OpenGL textures containing float 32 data (GL_RGBA32F format), in a desktop application (Windows/Linux, GLSL 4.2).

These textures contains results of precomputed physical data and could contains some NAN values where the precompute failed (this is "normal" in my application, some cases cannot be computed, this is rare but "normal")

I need to detect these values in the shader.

Is there any standard on handling NAN values in GLSL sampler ?

More specifically :

- is it sure that a NAN value written in a texture a read as NAN by "textureXXX" GLSL methods ?
- if a "textureXXX" method is called with non-NEAREST filtering and one of the interpolated values is a NAN, should I get a NAN value as result ?

Thanks.

## Edit :

As the answers says, nothing is required about NaN support in OpenGL specifications.

So I will :

- replace NaN values with a "special" value in case the NaN value in a texture is not read as NaN in GLSL
- implement the mipmapping by myself
- test all values against the "special" value

This is extra work, but seems to be necessary to ensure support of my invalid values on different platforms / different hardware.

Answer (score 2):

Section 2.3.4.1 of the OpenGL 4.5 compatibility spec says that "Implementations are permitted,
but not required, to support *Inf* s and *NaN* s in their floating-point computations."

<s>I didn't find any mention of NaN values in the texture minification section of the spec (8.14.2 in OpenGL 4.5 compatibility spec). However, the equations used in fragment minification seem fairly well specified, so I imagine implementations will respect NaN values in them. If you are afraid, however, you can use raw texture access functions to implement mipmapping yourself.</s> As Reto Koradi notes, texture functions may not return NaN values for filtered textures.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my interpretation of the spec, the answer is NO to both. The most conclusive evidence I found for this is in section 4.7.1 "Range and Precision" of recent GLSL specs (e.g. page 65 of the GLSL 4.20 spec):

> Operations and built-in functions that operate on a NaN are not required to return a NaN as the result.

The `texture()` GLSL calls are built-in functions, so I believe this rule applies to them, and you can't count on them returning NaN for textures that contain NaN values.

Answer (score 0):

### NaN in WebGL Textures

Textures with NaN values works for me in WebGL running in an intel iMac.    I guess it will work on other platforms too.  You need to use the OES_texture_float extension in WebGL1 before making the (float) texture from JS.

In the shader GLSL you can detect NaN like this...

```
vec4 data = texture2D(samplerData, tc);
bool bNaN = (data.r != data.r);
```

Also, you may need to scale all (float) texture values to be between 0 and 1 in JS before creating the WebGL texture.  Then you can use uniform values to scale them back in your GLSL shaders.